# Performance Issue Clearing Array of Objects in VBA with Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am having a performance issue clearing a large array of a objects in VBA with Excel.  The objects in the array are instances of a custom class that contain many dozens of properties.  A simplified version of the code looks something like this:

```
Sub SlowExampleDynamic()
    'Create an array consisting of a large number of objects with a user defined class.
    Dim ExampleArray() As CustomClass
    Dim i As Long  
    For i = 0 To 100000
        'Make a user defined class in memory at each array position
        ReDim Preserve ExampleArray(i)
        Set ExampleArray(i) = New CustomClass
        'Populate the user defined class with data
        Set ExampleArray(i) = GenerateClassData()
    Next i
    
    'The following line takes upwards of 5 minutes
    Erase ExampleArray
   
End Sub
```

The line `Erase ExampleArray` is taking upwards of 5 minutes.

I tried implementing this with a static array and clearing the elements in a loop, but get the same results:

```
Sub SlowStaticExample()
    'Create an array consisting of a large number of objects with a user defined class.
    Dim ExampleArray(100000) As CustomClass
    Dim i As Long  
    For i = 0 To 100000
        'Make a user defined class in memory at each array position
        Set ExampleArray(i) = New CustomClass
        'Populate the user defined class with data
        Set ExampleArray(i) = GenerateClassData()
    Next i
   
    'The following loop takes upwards of 5 minutes
    For i = 0 To 100000
        Set ExampleArray(i) = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```

However, if I run the same code as above bet never actually populate the CustomClass objects with data, the array clears in less than a second:

```
Sub FastExample()
    'Create an array consisting of a large number of objects with a user defined class.
    Dim ExampleArray(100000) As CustomClass
    Dim i As Long  
    For i = 0 To 100000
        'make a user defined class in memory at each array position
        Set ExampleArray(i) = New CustomClass
    Next i
   
    'The following loop will run in less than a second
    For i = 0 To 100000
        Set ExampleArray(i) = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```

I am working on tests that partially populate the CustomClass objects to try and identify a breaking point, but so far no luck with that approach.

What could cause the process of clearing the array of populated custom objects to take so long?

Comment: Are your class properties all non-object types, or are there nested objects within your class instances?

Comment: Two of the class properties are custom objects.  Each of those two custom objects have only non-object properties.  So, there is one level of nesting objects.

Comment: I think you're bumping up against a known issue in VBA and "classic" VB (from VB6) that destroying objects is very slow (compared eg. to VB5)